# Is there a tool that will allow for showing html from xslt and xml files to edit

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a xslt file and xml file.  In a .NET app, it takes these two files and creates the html output.  I now need to take a new xml file and modify the xslt file to output new html.  Is there a tool that allows me to look at the html output as I modify the xslt to get the look I want?  I have Altova suite, Visual Studio (all versions), DreamWeaver, and many other tools.  However, I can't seem to find any way to look at the html and modify the xslt.

Comment: notepad is tool enough to edit xslt files

Comment: I want to see the output and not just edit the file.

Comment: I believe you don't have a realistic understanding and experience in the XSLT development process -- nobody for the past 13 years has asked for such a tool. If you want to be distracted from your solving process it is enough to have kids.

Comment: Really? I did. Couldn't find one myself either, so I wrote one. Unfortunately it's still too buggy for general release, although there's a half-finished web version at http://www.flynn1179.net/xml/. I'm still having problems getting it to work on some browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

The [XSLT Debugger](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xslt_debugger.html) in oXygen XML Editor (or Developer) will allow you to view rendered XHTML output (or well-formed HTML).